# How to run something automatically in mongoDB server after certain time like in 60 days and change value of document without any user interaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend

Condition is like this.

1. How to allow a user to insert a document(data) in the collection(table) which will expire at 90 days .On the 85th day and on the 90th day Server will send a notification as a reminder for expiry date and in 90th day it be will be sent to the trash for 30 days and again in the trash server will give notification on the 28th day (118th total life of data )and then on the 30th day  as reminder sent notification that it will be deleted from the database and be deleted.

2.How can i automatically change the document value like on the 60th day a document in the database will go from (visible:true) to (visible:false) after when the user extends the time to 90th from 60 days then it will changed to (visible:true) again.The problem is just here to change the value to false automatically without user interaction with the app on 60th day.

i am currently trying to do it on Node.js using express.

Answer (score 0):

The core MongoDB server does not implement scheduling, but if you use Atlas you can use [Atlas Triggers](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/triggers/#scheduled-triggers).